# Cannot access a closed Stream? How to prevent it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to run this code but I always get an error "cannot access a closed Stream"

```
private MemoryStream GetBitmap(Stream stream, int width, int height)
        {
            const int size = 150;
            const int quality = 75;

            using (var image = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)))
            {
                //int width, height;
                if (image.Width > image.Height)
                {
                    width = size;
                    height = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height * size / (double)image.Width);
                }
                else
                {
                    width = Convert.ToInt32(image.Width * size / (double)image.Height);
                    height = size;
                }

                var resized = new Bitmap(width, height);
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
                {
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var qualityParamId = Encoder.Quality;
                        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityParamId, quality);
                        var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
                            .FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);

                        resized.Save(output, codec, encoderParameters);

                        return output;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Not sure how can I prevent Memorystream output from closing a Stream stream.

EDIT
After your suggestions here is the new code

```
public Stream GetBitmap(Stream stream)
        {
            using (var image = SystemDrawingImage.FromStream(stream))
            {
                var scaled = ScaledSize(image.Width, image.Height, ThumbnailSize);
                var resized = new Bitmap(scaled.width, scaled.height);
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
                using (var attributes = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    attributes.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, resized.Width, resized.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

                    using (var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
                    using (var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)Quality))
                    {
                        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

                        var streamOutput = new MemoryStream();
                        resized.Save(streamOutput, systemDrawingJpegCodec, encoderParams);

                        return streamOutput;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the controller action method

```
   [HttpGet("{photoId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPhoto(intphotoId)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(photoid))
                return NotFound();

            var response = await _service.GetPhotoAsync(photoId);

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new ContentDisposition()
            {
                FileName = "test.jpg",
                Inline = true
            }.ToString());

            return File(response, "image/jpeg");

        }
```

Comment: Don't use `using` on it. You return the Stream, thus the function calling it can implement the `using` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the `MemoryStream` in a using block. When the block goes out of scope the `Dispose` method is being called. Just remove the `using` so that it isn't closed:

```
var output = new MemoryStream())

var qualityParamId = Encoder.Quality;
var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityParamId, quality);
var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
    .FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);

resized.Save(output, codec, encoderParameters);

return output;
```

Also, if you're planning to have the caller read the stream then you'll probably want to reset the `Position` property so that anyone reading from it starts from the beginning:

```
output.Position = 0;
return output;
```

Comment: When I remove using from the MemoryStream part, the script is just running forever. I tried returning stream before the start of the code, and it works fine. But when i try to run image manipulation code with your suggestion I get this new issue

Comment: @Jimi could you please elaborate?

Comment: You're encoding, not decoding a Bitmap.

Comment: @mko You should also dispose of the `encoderParameters` object. The `EncoderParameters` and the `Encoder/Decoder` are usually initialized outside any `using` block; the `EncoderParameters` object disposed in a `finally` section.

Comment: @Jimi i have updated my code in original question, please check. The error is still there....

Comment: @mko - Just added some more information about setting the `Position` property on the stream.